# How to compile and run C programs avoiding "bash: ./a.out: Permission denied"

Tags: 10.10, gcc, c

I have installed GCC compiler by installing the `build-essential` package.

After the installation I wrote a simple C program. I tried to run it with the following command:

```
gcc First.c
./a.out
```

but I'm getting a `bash: ./a.out: Permission denied` message. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute .out files, getting permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44675/cant-execute-out-files-getting-permission-denied) (The `chmod` commands suggested in the answers here are extremely unlikely to help, for reasons described there.)

Answer (score 5):

give that program (I mean `a.out`) the permission to "be executed" by this command:

```
chmod +x ./a.out
```

then execute it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command

```
ls -l a.out
```

This will show the permissions granted to the file like below.

`-rw-r--r--` `1 js js 0 2011-03-27 19:45 a.out`

The first set is permissions and to execute it as such you need permission 'execute'
Grant the execute permission using 
`chmod +x a.out` or `chmod 755 a.out`

Comment: `sh ./a.out` is not going to work. This is a binary, not a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the executable file `a.out` doesn't have the execute (+x) mode set.

Run the command `chmod a+x a.out` to give the user the right to run the file. After that you can execute the file by running `./a.out` in a terminal.

There's another way to achieve the same thing:

1) Right-click the `a.out` file in the file browser.

2) Select `Properties` from the drop-down menu

3) Open up the `Permissions` tab

4) Check the box `Allow to execute this file as a program`.