# Keepass 2 doesn't show any files present on a pendrive

Tags: database, keepass

I keep my keepass 2.x databases and their respective keyfiles in a pendrive, to be able to open them in any PC.

Whenever I want to open a database, first I have to execute Keepass 2, then navigate to the folder, right-click on the .kbdx file and select open with Keepass and after that I have to copy the keyfile to my home directory, because Keepass doesn't display any files present in the pendrive on the "open database file" window, it does only if these files are anywhere in the home folder ([as shown in this screenshot](http://imm.io/OqvN)).

I would prefer to just open them directly from the pendrive via Keepass if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153656/how-do-i-run-an-executable-truecrypt-file-from-a-pendrive), I got to an answer, the pendrive must be formatted as ext4, in order to have the necessary permission to view and open the files from there.