# How can I run a C program from Code Blocks?

Tags: xubuntu, code-blocks

This is my first time using Ubuntu to run a C-File with a codeBlocks

1. I tried save as a File "file1" without extension file.

   Permission Denied
2. I tried chmod u+x file1

   Wrong something but builded success
3. I tried give "file1.c"

   File not found

Comment: Did you build after saving it as `file1.cpp`? Is it even building correctly?

Comment: Open the terminal  ----> Go to the location of the file -----> type `g++ file1.cpp` and c file is saved with `.c` extention not `.cpp`.

Comment: @muru all Correctly

Comment: @Hunter Look like gpeddit with Terminal right

Comment: gedit is a text Editor. It is not a compiler. Have u installed  any compiler like clang (for c) or gcc (for c) or g++ (for C++)?

Comment: @Hunter Yes already gcc and g++

Comment: Is it c++ program or c program?

Comment: @Hunter c program

Comment: Follow all the steps in the [Code::Blocks Creating a new project](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project) wiki at codeblocks.org and please comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: @karel yes i did.
new Project > Console program > C > run main.c (Helloworld).
Result /.../Debug: File not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Any C program is saved with .c Extension. And C++ program is saved with .cpp extension.

Now coming to compilation,

1. If you want to compile it using Terminal, Open the terminal (Press CTRL + ALT + T).
2. Go to the directory where the file is saved. (You can use cd command to change directory).
3. After reaching the directory , type `gcc file1.c`.
4. If there are no errors, then you can run the output by typing `./a.out`.

Comment: so Codeblocks can't complie itsefl?

Comment: Yes, it Can compile , You can use the  "Build" option to compile

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're the owner of the files. If you're not, you can run:

```
sudo chown usrname:username /path/to/your/file
```

Also make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/file
```

Comment: Users generally own the files they create automatically, and compilers automatically set execute permissions on the executable binaries they create (unless they can't, for example due to the filesystem not supporting it, in which case manually running `chmod +x` will also fail). A compiler might not make the program executable for the user [if umask is set unusually](https://askubuntu.com/a/44752/22949), but then [a different `chmod` command would be needed as well](https://askubuntu.com/a/932719/22949).